# how to find two keydown event has fired in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

how to find if two keydown event has fired. I'm creating a search box in which after typing two letters the results slides in the page.. any suggestion

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  This is a good question, but the point of stack overflow is not for the community to code for you, rather to help you overcome problems/bugs/blocks in your code.  Read the faq's, specifically "What have you tried".

Comment: @Brain I think he haven't have any idea and he is asked a valid question for that we can consider him.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using .keydown() you can check the sender input length (what's in the search box) is greater than 2.

http://api.jquery.com/keydown/

For example

```
$('#myTextBox').keydown(function() {
    alert($(this).val().length);
})
```

However, it sounds like you might benefit from using jQueryUI and Autocomplete.  http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Answer (score 1):

You have to call a function in keyup event and then count the length of input of that input box.

Example:

```
<input name="test" id="test" onkeyup="search();"/>

<script>
function search()
{
  var textBox = document.getElementById("test");
  var textLength = textBox.value.length;
  if(textLength > 1)
  {
      // Do your stuff 
  }
}

</script>
```

Use it wisely it should work. Cheers :)

Comment: hey i did what u wrote and it worked thanks. but as i'm coming from 2 letters to 1 the slide is not going where it was i added the animation that if length <2 do an animation. i used setinterval function but that also doesn't work pls help

Comment: $("#search_text_area").keydown(function() {
        if($(this).val().length > 1 ) {
           $('.search_result_container').animate({right:'0'},500,'easeInOutQuint')
       }
      else
      {
       $('.search_result_container').animate({right:'-100%'},500,'easeInOutQuint');
      }
    });

Comment: pls share your javascript error. Check it in firefox for javascript error.

Answer (score 1):

you could just count the characters, like

```
$("#your_input_id").on("keyup", function() {
   if( $.trim($(this).val().length) >= 2 ) {
       //show suggestions
   }
});
```